# Net-SNMP adding .mib files

Tags: net-snmp

I got this to work years ago on a different system but I can't get it working now.  I'm using Net-SNMP 5.5 x64 on Windows 7 x64 (all the later versions crash) and I'm trying to load the .mib files for Xerox Printers (http://origin-download.support.xerox.com/pub/drivers/MIBs/) into it so I can do calls like

```
   snmptranslate -m ALL -On XEROX-SERVICE-MONITORING-MIB::xcmSvcMonServiceStateDetail.27
```

I tried to put the files in the asn folder into my share/snmp/mibs folder, however when I do this I big mess of errors and it doesn't do the lookup

```
Desktop>snmptranslate -m +XEROX-COMMON-MIB snmptranslate -m ALL -On XEROX-SERVICE-MONITORING-MIB::xcmSvcMonServiceStateDetail.27
Cannot find module (IANA-CHARSET-MIB): At line 23 inC:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one
Cannot find module (Job-Monitoring-MIB): At line 32 in C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one
Cannot find module (Printer-MIB): At line 41 in C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one
Did not find 'IANACharset' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'jmJobEntry' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'jmJobState' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'jmJobStateReasons1' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'jmNumberOfInterveningJobs' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'jmJobKOctetsPerCopyRequested' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'jmJobKOctetsProcessed' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'jmJobImpressionsPerCopyRequested' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'jmJobImpressionsCompleted' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'PresentOnOff' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'prtGeneralEntry' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'prtInputEntry' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'prtOutputEntry' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'prtChannelEntry' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'prtInterpreterEntry' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Did not find 'prtInterpreterIndex' in module #-1 (C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one)
Unlinked OID in XEROX-COMMON-MIB: mib-2 ::= { mgmt 1 }
Undefined identifier: mgmt near line 38532 of C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/xerox.one 
snmptranslate:  (Sub-id not found: (top) -> snmptranslate)
```

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Seems like I made a mistake when testing and wasn't putting the -On in place.  Eitherway if someone knows how to fix these errors I would appreciate it.

Comment: snmptranslate -m +XEROX-COMMON-MIB snmptranslate -m ALL -On XEROX-SERVICE-MONITORING-MIB::xcmSvcMonServiceStateDetail.27  is I presume a copy/paste error due to repeated "snmptranslate -m"

Answer (score 2):

Try **`net-snmp-config --default-mibdirs`** to view the current search path(s).

And, if that's different that you expect, you can try adding to your `snmptranslate` command a **`-M +C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs`** and **`-m ALL`** to add any MIBs in `C:/usr/share/snmp/mibs`.

`man snmpcmd` shows

```
snmpcmd - options and behaviour common to most of the Net-SNMP command-line tools
```

// SNIP

```
   -m MIBLIST
          Specifies  a  colon  separated list of MIB modules (not files) to load for this application.  This overrides (or augments) the environment variable MIBS, the snmp.conf
          directive mibs, and the list of MIBs hardcoded into the Net-SNMP library.

          If MIBLIST has a leading '-' or '+' character, then the MIB modules listed are loaded in addition to the default list, coming before or after this  list  respectively.
          Otherwise, the specified MIBs are loaded instead of this default list.

          The special keyword ALL is used to load all MIB modules in the MIB directory search list.  Every file whose name does not begin with "." will be parsed as if it were a
          MIB file.

   -M DIRLIST
          Specifies a colon separated list of directories to search for MIBs.  This overrides (or augments) the environment variable MIBDIRS, the  snmp.conf  directive  mibdirs,
          and the default directory hardcoded into the Net-SNMP library (/usr/share/snmp/mibs).

          If  DIRLIST  has  a leading '-' or '+' character, then the given directories are added to the default list, being searched before or after the directories on this list
          respectively.  Otherwise, the specified directories are searched instead of this default list.

          Note that the directories appearing later in the list have have precedence over earlier ones.  To avoid searching any MIB  directories,  set  the  MIBDIRS  environment
          variable to the empty string ("").

          Note  that  MIBs specified using the -m option or the mibs configuration directive will be loaded from one of the directories listed by the -M option (or equivalents).
          The mibfile directive takes a full path to the specified MIB file, so this does not need to be in the MIB directory search list.
```

Comment: net-snm-config is not included in this package from Net-SNMP

Comment: ok, that is a pity; but still worth trying -M to ensure MIBDIRS environment is ok.

Comment: Regarding Windows specifics, I see at https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB25949 instructions for setting up MIBDIRS environment

Comment: I was using net-snmp 0.5.7.0.1 on windows (because this version has binaries) and 0.5.7.3 on linux (because the source does compile unlike for windows), is 0.5.5 not way to old?